# overridePendingTransition causes error : java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent

Tags: android

I have an app in which when user taps on a button it takes him to a new activity through an animation. The pressed back the previous activity is created again using animation (transition in/out). Doing this fast cause an error.

code:

```
    startActivity(intent);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in,R.anim.slide_out);
    finish();
```

Error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3339)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3210)
at android.widget.ViewAnimator.addView(ViewAnimator.java:184)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3155)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3131)
at com.myapps.tryanim.w.onAnimationEnd(Unknown Source)
at android.view.animation.AnimationSet.getTransformation(AnimationSet.java:400)
at android.view.animation.Animation.getTransformation(Animation.java:940)
at android.view.View.drawAnimation(View.java:13200)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13339)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2928)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2797)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13710)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12645)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12689)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2910)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12583)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12689)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2910)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12583)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12689)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2910)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12583)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12689)
at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:1198)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2173)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2045)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1854)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What could be problem here.

slide_in xml-anim

```
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="100%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:duration="800" />
```

slide_out xml

```
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="-100%"
    android:duration="800" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer myself as the problem was not in the animations, it was with the UI widgets I was adding. So what I did was first removed all the UI widgets and then called the animations so when the new activity starts it has all the UI widgets first removed (if any present) then added again.